# Image of Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, mobius-transformation

What's the image of the first quadrant $Rez\ge0$ and $Imz\ge0$ under transformation $f(z)=(i-z)/(i+z)$?
I know that real axis is mapped to the unit circle, $f(0+i*0)=1$ and $f(\infty)=-1 $.

Comment: Contrary to what you said you know, the imaginary axis is not mapped to the unit circle.  For example, $i$ is mapped to 0.

Comment: From my calculations $f(0,i)=-i$

Comment: $f$ is define, in your question, as a function of one variable, so $f(0,i)$ makes no sense. I suspect that you might be writing $f(a,b)$ when you mean $f(a+bi$; that would explain the equation $f(0,0)=1$ in your question. But then $f(i)$ would be $f(0,1)$, not $f(0,i)$. So I don't know what you mean by $f(0,i)$ or why it's relevant.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $w=f(z)$, and rearrange to make $z$ the subject of the formula. In your rearranged form for $z$, write $w=u+iv$. Multiply top and bottom of the fraction by the conjugate of the denominator so that you can identify the real and imaginary parts of $z$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. Now you can apply the inequality conditions given in the question, giving you inequalities for $u$ and $v$. You will end up with a region in the complex plane.

Comment: I just followed your method. Is the end result supposed to be the interior of the lower half of the unit circle?

Comment: @JessyCat: I get the upper half of the interior of the unit circle, not the lower half, i.e. $u^2+v^2\leq1 \cap v\geq0$

Comment: hmm. I'll have to check my arithmetic.

Comment: no, I got the lower half again. b/c $z = \displaystyle \frac{i(1+w)}{1-w} = \displaystyle \frac{i(1+u+iv)}{(1-(u+iv)} = \displaystyle \frac{i+ui-v}{1-u-iv} = \displaystyle \frac{-v + i(1+u)}{(1-u)-iv}\cdot \frac{(1-u)+iv}{(1-u)+iv} = \displaystyle \frac{-v(1-u)-iv^{2}+i(u+1)(1-u) - v(u+1)}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}}$

Comment: (continued) $ = \displaystyle  \frac{[-v(1-u)-v(u+1)]+i[(1+u)(1-u)-v^{2}]}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} = \displaystyle  \frac{-v+vu-vu-v + i[1-u^{2}-v^{2}]}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} = \displaystyle \frac{-2v}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} + \displaystyle \frac{(1-u^{2}-v^{2})}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}}i$

Comment: (continued) So then, $Re z = \displaystyle \frac{-2v}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} > 0$, which implies that $-2v > 0$, which can only happen if $v<0$. If I made a mistake somewhere, please check and let me know. It's important I get this right!

Comment: and I just tested the point $(x,y)=(1,1)$. Under $w$, $(1,1)$ becomes $w = \displaystyle  \frac{1+i-i}{1+i+i} = \displaystyle  \frac{1}{1+2i}\frac{(1-2i)}{(1-2i)} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{5}i$, which is in the lower half.

Comment: @Jessy Cat..I have $z=\frac{i-wi}{w+1}$

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. We're starting with different $w$'s, so I wasn't doing the exact same exercise. Oops. With the $w$ you have, I'm sure the sign would be different. I apologize.

Comment: I hope that's all OK now @ Jessy Cat