# Find the image of $0<x<1$ under the Mobius transformation $w = \frac{z-1}{z-2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

I need to find the image of the strip $0<x<1$ if $w = \frac{z-1}{z-2}$.

To approach this problem, I followed the advice of David Quinn on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253076/image-of-m%C3%B6bius-transformation), and solved $w = \frac{z-1}{z-2}$ for $z$. So, $z=\frac{1-2w}{1-w}$.

Then, since $w = u+iv$, I substituted $u+iv$ in for $w$ above, and multiplied top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the bottom to obtain $\frac{1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} - i \frac{v}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}}$.

Now, $x = Re\,z =\frac{1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} $, so what we need is $ 0 < \frac{1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}} < 1$.

For $0 < \frac{1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}}$, we really only need $0 < 1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}$. So, by completing the square, I get that the area that should make that quantity $> 0$ is the exterior of a circle centered at $(3/4,0)$ with radius $1/4$, or $1 < \displaystyle \frac{(u-3/4)^{2}}{(1/4)^{2}} + \frac{v^{2}}{(1/4)^{2}}$.

For $1 > \displaystyle \frac{1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}}$, by completing the square again, I get that the area that should make that quantity $< 1$ is the interior of a circle centered at $\left(\frac{1}{2},0 \right)$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$.

And also, we need to be sure to omit the point $(1,0)$ because that makes the denominator in $\displaystyle \frac{1-3u+2u^{2}+2v^{2}}{(1-u)^{2}+v^{2}}$ zero.

I know I went wrong somewhere, because these two areas together don't make any sense. It's almost like the $0>$ part was redundant. So, I'm assuming I made a mistake.

Can someone please help me fix it?

Comment: The first circle should have centre $(\frac34,0)$.  Does this fix the problem?  I didn't check any further.

Comment: BTW are you instructed that you have to use this method?  There are much easier ways.

Comment: @David, I don't have to, but I don't really know/understand how else to do it.

Comment: I was going to write you an easier method but Jonas did it first.

Comment: @David, I'm still having trouble deciphering what Jonas did, quite honestly. I'm about to ask him a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say that you complicate too much.

The simplest approach is to note that Möbius transformations **with matrix with real entries having determinant $\pm1$ (added after benji's comment)** take vertical lines and circles centered at the real line to vertical lines or circles centered at the real line. In this case, for $x=0$ it gives the circle intersecting the real line at $1/2$ and at $$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{iy-1}{iy-2}=1.$$ Similarly, for $x=1$ it gives the circle intersecting the real line at $0$ and at$$\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{1+iy-1}{1+iy-2}=\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{iy}{iy-1}=1.$$

Comment: what is a circle centered at the real line? You mean a circle centered at a point (x,0) (or (u,0) under the transformation)? So, Jonas, what you're saying is, literally figure out where the boundaries map to under the Mobius transformation and then figure out where within those  image boundaries the whole image lies?

Comment: Also, how is $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to + \infty}\frac{iy-1}{iy-2} = 1$? Or $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to + \infty} \frac{i}{iy-1} = 1$? I don't understand the logic behind either of those statements. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Right, a circle centered at some point $(u,0)$. And yes, it is sufficient to know the boundary points. The limits are computed simply diving by $i$ above and below, and letting $y\to+\infty$. In other words, all works as if you were taking the limits in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: ah! I think I've got it now! Thank you!

Comment: just wondering where within those circles is the correct area? I'm getting conflicting answers.

Comment: Simple also: take any point inside $0<x<1$ and see where it goes. For example, $x=1/2$ goes to $1/3$ and this tells you where are the others (the region between the two circles).

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be outside one of the circles...

Comment: Because of the $\frac{(u-3/4)^2}{(1/4)^{2}} + \frac{v^{2}}{(1/4)^{2}} > 1$ part. I checked and checked to see if it was a mistake and it's not.

Comment: Draw the two circles: one centered at $3/4$ and radius $1/4$, the other centered at $1/2$ and radius $1/2$. The region that you want is the are between the two. $1/3$ is precisely between the two.

Comment: I did that. What I want to know is why it's not matching up with what I did analytically. Unless I can reconcile the two, I won't really be able to understand how to do these kinds of problems.

Comment: I see. I didn't look at your formulas.

Comment: wait a minute...  I did something really stupid. Drew the dang circle wrong. Now, it's all good! :)

Comment: it is the area inside the circle with radius $1/2$ and not inside the one with radius $1/4$! :)

Comment: @Jonas I believe that your first sentence is wrong. Mobius transformations don't always take vertical lines to vertical lines or circles centered at the real line to circles centered at the real line. For example, $z \to e^{i\pi/2}$ takes the imaginary line to the real line. They take lines and circles to lines and circles (not necessarily respectively). The method I am familiar with in this kind of questions, is to use that fact, and take 3 points from the line or circle, see where they are mapped to, and conclude the image of it.

Comment: @benji Quite right, but the matrix has determinant $-1$. Will add it now.

Comment: @JessyCat one method to compute the area is this. Let's take the imaginary line from your example, once you figure its image, you can use the fact that Mobius transformation preserves angles. Say you find that the points $0, i, \infty$ are mapped to $0, 1+i, 2$ respectively. This tells you that the imaginary line is mapped to the circle around $z=1$ with radius 1. Moreover, $x > 0$ is to the right of the imaginary line (when going from $0$ to $i$ to $\infty$ in that order. Therefore the image of $x>0$ will be to the right of the circle, when passing through the image points in the same order

Comment: ...so it will be the interior of the circle.